# S4 Classes May Not Contain "try-error" Class Objects?

Tags: r, validation, r-s4

Reproducible example:

```
setClass("test", representation(a="ANY"))
A <- structure("blahblahblah", class="try-error")
new("test", a=A)
# Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “test” object: blahblahblah
```

I think the problem stems from line 29 of `validObject`:

```
sloti <- try(switch(namei, .S3Class = S3Class(object), 
  slot(object, namei)), silent = TRUE)
```

which clearly will trick whatever follows when `slot(object, namei)` returns a `try-error` class object as is the case here.

Anyhow, just wanted to ask here if this seems like a bug to anyone else before I go off and propose a `tryCatch` alternate.

And if you're curious as to why on earth I would be doing something like this, I am building S4 classes to store results of arbitrary expression evaluations, which in one of my test cases happened to contain the result of a `try()` statement.

Comment: a partial work-around might be `x = new("test"); x@a=A` (slot assignment doesn't trigger validity check) but yes, it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

No, the issue is on the next line:

```
if (inherits(sloti, "try-error")) {
   errors <- c(errors, sloti)
   next
}
```

A hacky workaround would be:

```
safeNew <- function(...) {
  suppressMessages(trace(validObject, quote(inherits <- function(...)
    if (eval.parent(substitute(namei != '.S3Class' && class(slot(object, namei)) == 'try-error'))) FALSE
    else base::inherits(...)), at = 11))
  capture.output(res <- new(...))
  suppressMessages(untrace(validObject))
  res
}

setClass("test", representation(a="ANY"))
A <- structure("blahblahblah", class="try-error")
safeNew("test", a = A) # Now returns no error.
```

EDIT: I changed some code above so it now type checks correctly rather than disable type checking. For example,

```
setClass("test", representation(a="ANY", b = "character"))
A <- structure("blahblahblah", class="try-error")
safeNew("test", a = A, b = 5) 
# Error in validObject(.Object) :
#  invalid class “test” object: invalid object for slot "b" in class "test": got class "numeric", should be or extend class "character"
```

Comment: I think it's six on one hand... but my view is the core source of the bug is that `try` is used instead of `tryCatch`.  Also, will your code now ignore all errors at that step? If so I'm not sure that is the correct outcome.

Comment: @BrodieG Yes, but it's fixed now. It will now type check everything else, including `try-error`s, if there is an error in that switch statement.

Comment: +1, not exactly an answer, but interesting use of trace as a workaround to maintain the rest of `new` functionality.